# Transparent image viewer

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any image viewing software where i can make the image slightly see-through and that the mouse will ignore?

Essentially something i can use to trace an image to a drawing program below.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a (better?) alternative. Use Inkscape.

Open/Import the image in Inkscape and lock the layer. Then create a new layer on top of that and do the tracing on the new layer. You can toggle visibility of the bottom layer to have an idea of the current status of your tracing work.

Learn more from [Inkscape wiki](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Layer_Dialog).